# Recursively set NTFS Permissions

Tags: powershell, recursion, permissions, batch-file, ntfs

So basically we have a large shared drive which contains a lot of top level folders each containing many sub folders and files.

```
E:\Share\%Username%
E:\Share\%Username%\Folder1
E:\Share\%Username%\Folder2
E:\Share\%Username%\Folder2\Folder3
```

Within each of these folders are files - now basically over time the permissions have gone haywire and what I want to do is basically take ownership of absolutely everything within the top level:

```
E:\Share\%username%\
```

But also to set it so that anything within that folder will inherit permissions from it's parent folder so anything in:

```
E:\Share\%Username%\[Whatever is at this level and below] (whether files or folders)
```

inherit from:

```
E:\Share\%username%\
```

Can this be doen via batch script?

Answer (score 5):

Take ownership of the folder E:\Share\%Username%\ and all its contents recursively:

```
takeown /f "E:\Share\%Username%\" /r
```

Answer (score 3):

There really is no reason to re-invent the wheel here, you can use icacls in Windows 7 from the cmd prompt or from PS, its a one liner, can take ownership and has recursive built-in.

What you really what to do, is:
Take ownership (optional most of the time)
Set inheritance
Recursively apply.

http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html

If you are using XP / 2003 then xcacls is available instead.